# Is there a pre-packed vanilla Apache Felix installation with Jetty 9?

Tags: jetty, osgi, bundle

Is there somewhere I can download a plain Apache Felix with all the bundles required for running the latest Jetty 9?

I've been trying to do this by following the Jetty documentation to no avail, it's like trying to put together a puzzle where you don't know where the missing pieces are. Some of the bundles you get from Maven, others from the lib folder from a Jetty installation, and others you download from Eclipse Orbit.

NOTE: it would be great if the Jetty project just provided a zip file with all needed bundles for OSGi on each release, or even better, create a FatJar bundle, that by just releasing a FullJetty bundle would start the whole thing without having a zillion bundles that you never really use directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just take a look at the [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org) project it's a OSGi Container based on Felix/Equinox and brings Jetty along with Pax-Web as service Layer. 
The most benefit of this server is that you just don't need to care much about all those infrastructure bundles and just unpack it and develop your OSGi application with it.

Comment: Karaf doesn't include Jetty anymore, also I need the latest version because I need servlet 3.1

Comment: Of course it does, just install the http or http-whiteboard or war feature. Oh  and in case you need Servlet 3.1, Karaf 4.0.0.M3 will be released this week (or take the already released M2) it also brings along Jetty 9

Comment: Awesome, I'll wait for Karaf 4 then, also, there is this embedded Felix in-house OSGi framework another team has, so still, it would be nice to get Jetty 9 up and running in a plain Felix instance.

Comment: And another thing, what I don't like about Karaf is that it takes them quite some time to update the container, they are just updating to servlets 3.1 and now servlets 4.0 is about to come out! and also they tend to lag behind on Felix releases. I'd like some way to stay more up to date.

Comment: If you don't like it, it's open source get yourself involved!

Comment: You know what, you're right... I'm gonna get into the user mailing list and start from there, maybe I can help out, any pointers on how to commit? I see on your profile you are a Karaf commiter

Comment: Start with the users mailinglists user@karaf.apache.org  (details - http://karaf.apache.org/index/community/mailing-lists.html) get yourself involved, take a look at the jira issues for low-hanging fruits. Start looking at the ops4j users list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ops4j again take a look at the low-hanging fruits at ops4j. If you find something not working, create a jira (https://ops4j1.jira.com/projects/PAXWEB) fixes can be provided by pull requests (https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web)